# How can I scrape data from this website (multiple webpages) using R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am a beginner in scraping data from website. It seems difficult for me to interpret the structure of html using XML or other packages.
Can anyone help me to download the data from this website?

http://wszw.hzs.mofcom.gov.cn/fecp/fem/corp/fem_cert_stat_view_list.jsp

It is about the investment from China. The character set is in Chinese.

What I've tried so far:

```
library("rvest")

url <- "http://wszw.hzs.mofcom.gov.cn/fecp/fem/corp/fem_cert_stat_view_list.jsp" 

firm <- url %>% 
  html() %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="Grid1MainLayer"]/table[1]') %>% 
  html_table() 

firm <- firm[[1]] head(firm)
```

Comment: What code have you tried. There are _hundreds_ of examples of this on SO and _thousands_ on the web. What effort have you put into this so far?

Comment: Sorry that I did not tried many codes.
`library("rvest")
url <- "http://wszw.hzs.mofcom.gov.cn/fecp/fem/corp/fem_cert_stat_view_list.jsp"
firm <- url %>%
  html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="Grid1MainLayer"]/table[1]') %>%
  html_table()
firm <- firm[[1]]

head(firm)`

Comment: Another try:

`url<-html("http://wszw.hzs.mofcom.gov.cn/fecp/fem/corp/fem_cert_stat_view_list.jsp")`
`selector_name<-"tr.listTableBody td div"`

`fnames<-html_nodes(url, selector_name) %>% html_text()`
`head(fnames)`

THe variables are messed up. How can I transform them into a table?
@hrbrmstr @Lorenzo Rossi

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the function in the XML package called readHTMLTable that should download all the tables in the page and already format it into a data.frame.

```
library(XML)
all_tables = readHTMLTable("http://wszw.hzs.mofcom.gov.cn/fecp/fem/corp/fem_cert_stat_view_list.jsp")
```

Then since there is only one table in the page you linked it should be enough to get the first element so:

```
target_table = all_tables[[1]]
```

Comment: THanks! I tried this code, it does not work. It gives results with a series of variables in one. It also gives Unrecognizable Code of Chinese and how can I read the table in the next page?

Comment: I have also tried the codes in 
http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/
[code]
library("rvest")
url <- "http://wszw.hzs.mofcom.gov.cn/fecp/fem/corp/fem_cert_stat_view_list.jsp"
firm <- url %>%
  html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="Grid1MainLayer"]/table[1]') %>%
  html_table()
firm <- firm[[1]]

head(firm)
[/code]
It still fails.